# Highcharts: cutom tooltip (useHTML: true) z-index issue over resetZoomButton

Tags: highcharts

My issue is as following:

I've created a custom tooltip with formatter callback function and had set useHTML attribute to be true.
The problem with useHTML is that it is not respecting z-indexing, and the result is that whenever i zoom in the chart (when the reset zoom button actually appears), the reset button's text gets covered by the tooltip's text.

```
   tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        followPointer: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>sSsSsSsSsSsSsssssssssssssssssssssS<br/>sdsdsddddddddddddssd</b>';
        }
   }
```

check this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sahar_rehani/R5Ep4/

try zooming in and then get the tooltip closest to the reset zoom button :)
please help!!!

Comment: the problem here is that setting the tooltip as html, the tooltip is rendered in a div which stays outside the graph svg, with position abosulte, and since the reset button is part of the svg, if the tooltip stays above the svg then it stays above the button. When the tooltip is not html you may see (firebug) that it is rendered inside the svg as one of its element so the "z-index" is handled properly. I think there isn't IMHO any simple solution to this, without hard coding the highcharts library.

Comment: So how come only the tooltip's text gets rendered above ? not anything else..

Answer (score 2):

There's a hacky way to change Highcharts tooltip `zIndex`:

```
chart.tooltip.label.attr({zIndex: 300});
```

Try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rinatio/2fehuLjn/)

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove useHTML: true line and your problem is resolved!. I know it is not the perfect solution but will do the job. z-index issues are very common when you mix svg and html. I will follow up if i find a better solution. You don't need useHTML: true to do the formatting that you are doing.

```
        tooltip: {
            followPointer: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>sSsSsSsSsSsSsssssssssssssssssssssS<br />sdsdsddddddddddddssd</b>';
            }
        },
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashyap02004/MuvL7/1/)

Comment: Link broken =/. I'm doing some more custom html stuff so getting rid of useHTML is not an option. any other suggestions?